# Hindi font in pdf generator in flutter not working

Tags: flutter, pdf

I am using `pdf: ^3.8.4` and

```
final font =
    await rootBundle.load("assets/fonts/Devanagari.ttf");
final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(font);
```

above code to add font and I have already tried the following fonts

`Devanagari.ttf Hind-Regular.ttf TiroDevanagariHindi-Regular.ttf`

but non of these work perfectly.

[Error in generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kRlj.png) and [destroyed hindi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hz8c.png)

So which font do I need to use to solve this problem?